# iPhone App :Can we change label backgroundcolor of more then one  labels in a single or minimum steps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my iPhone App there are almost 40 nib files (xibs) and in All of them  there is a label as a footer

is there any way to change the background color of all that label in a faster way instead of changing them in all xib one bty one?

Comment: You didn't inherit properly, there's your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you are using 40 labels for 40 nibs. You can add that label to main window and make your viewController a little bit smaller so that the label is visible everytime and thus you don't need to change color in 40 nib files.

Answer (score 1):

The NIB files are just XML so if they follow a similar pattern (naming etc) then you could find and replace the colour property in the xml itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the `UILabel` prgrammatically in your code.

Then use:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor myApplicationColor;
```